# Active current page using php not working

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in header.php:

```
<?php

 $page = "";
?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pos">
   <li <?php if ($page == "home") { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
   <li <?php if($page == 'about') { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a></li>
   <li <?php if($page == 'contact'){ ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li>
   <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-rotate-90"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

and on every page i put this code(and the name change depends on current page):

```
<?php include 'header.php';
  $page = 'about' ?>
```

and in css i made this:

```
.active{color:red }
```

But it is not working... any idea why?

Thank you for time, I really appreciate it

Comment: $page always contains the empty string only at the point where you output that navigation, because that is the value you have assigned to it. Changing the value only much later, after you have already output that navigation code, is not going to change anything any more, PHP is not a time machine.

Comment: Where do you include your header.php ? Can you show us the code as is please ?

Comment: No need to set and include anything . do only this:-`<?php 
$page = explode('.',end(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))[0];
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pos">
 <li <?php if ($page == "home") { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
 <li <?php if($page == 'aboutus') { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a></li>
 <li <?php if($page == 'contactus'){ ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li>
 <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-rotate-90"></i></a></li>
</ul>`

Comment: eddy abikhalil  did you tried my comment code?is it working?

Answer (score 0):

first you should remove `$page = "";` from header

```
<?php
  $page = "";//remove this line in header file
?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pos">
```

Second in every page swap these two lines

```
<?php
   $page = 'about';//swap these lines
   include 'header.php' ;   
?>
```

**some details:** when header load then `$page` is empty and your conditions false in `li` tag. so, before header load you should assign value to `$page`

**the best way:** you should used `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of hard coded `$page`. Example:

```
$url= explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$page = end($request_array);//this show your_page.php
$page=preg_replace('"\.php$"', '', $page )//this will remove .php extension
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `header.php` you explicitly set `$page = ""` - which means none of the checks for `$page == 'about'`(etc) are passing.

Although you do set `$page = 'about'` in your main script, this is after the code in `header.php` has run, and its html output produced.

The solution is simple:

1) remove the `$page = ""` from `header.php`

2) set `$page = "about"` (or equivalent) *before* the include

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using jQuery just adding this script in the footer section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get current URL path and assign 'active' class
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $('.nav > li > a[href="'+pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

In your case, this will work.

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('.nav li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
});
```